# WSO2 try it function doesn't work

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I installed wso2 api manager and i changed db from internal h2 db to an external MySql database.
I note that when i click on try it option wso2 console shows me a blank tab.

Has someone got my problem?

Thanks
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It depends of apache web server placed in front of che backend api-manager server. 
When I click on "try it" tab the api manager try to load the context "/registry" that i didn't define in web server before.

Now all works correctly.

Thanks
Stefano